# I want to deserialize a json object in scala

Tags: scala, jackson, json-serialization

```
    {
      "columnreq": [
        {
          "column": "date",
          "datatype": "string"
        },
        {"column": "name",
          "datatype": "int"
        }
      ],
      "databaseName": "test",
      "sourceTableName": "department"
    }
```

I want to read the values using jackson and get the values of `column` and `datatype` in single variables with variable names as `column` and `datatype` in a list or a map.

Comment: There is plenty of documentation on this. What have you tried? What specific problem are you having?

Answer (score 1):

Json serialization libraries always pick the name before `:` as the variable name and whatever written after `:` as the value of it.

You can write:

```
case class Column (column: String, dataType: String)

case class MyContainer(columnReq: List[Column], databaseName: String, sourceTableName: String)
```

or if you want to further process it after writing it this way,
you can write:

```
val container: MyContainer = parseJson(myJsonString) 

case class ModifiedContainer(Map[String, String], databaseName: String, sourceTableName: String)

ModifiedContainer(
   container.columnReq.map(column => (column.column, column.dataType)).toMap,
 container.databaseName,
 container.sourceTableName
)
```